# Spring Security with JWT

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am trying to develop Spring Security project with JWT.
I want access Login api with out Spring Security (without JWT token). But with below configuration, every time (for login api as well) it is checking for JWT token giving me 403 error.

Below is my WebSecurityConfig.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private JwtAuthFilter jwtAuthFilter;

@Autowired
private TokenAuthenticationService jwtAuthenticationProvider;

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)  throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider);
}



@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/api/v1/login");
    http.csrf().disable();

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For login path configuration something like this can be used:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER").and().formLogin()
            .usernameParameter("username") // default is username
            .passwordParameter("password") // default is password
            .loginPage("/authentication/login") // default is /login with an HTTP get
            .failureUrl("/authentication/login?failed") // default is /login?error
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authentication/login/process"); // default is /login
                                                                    // with an HTTP
                                                                    // post
}
```

If some paths need to be ignored `configure(WebSecurity web)` can be overridden:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/somepath").antMatchers("/static/**");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any clean way like (ignoringAntMatchers) so that I can check this in configure(HttpSecurity http) ?

Comment: Not sure about ant marchers, but in case if you need just configure login path, I've edited the reply, added there example from docs for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is filter class named JwtAuthFilter that is being executed before every service you call.

```
.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

this code provides to be executed filter before every request, but its okay, you have to see this FilterClass there must be some check if token doesnt exist filter class must be returned and request will directly go to the login service. if you can show that Filter class and I will help you.