# Combining Spring Security and Active Directory with JWT-Tokens

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory, jwt

I am currently working on building an Angular2-Application accessing a Spring Boot backend server for authentication and editing database data via REST-APIs. My current basic configuration to authenticate against our Active Directory looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()).userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
}
@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(AD_DOMAIN, "ldap://" + AD_URL);
    provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

    return provider;
}
```

This works so that I can access the basic Spring Boot Actuator-APIs after logging in using the default Boot Login Form.

The next step would be intertwining the activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider with a token-based authentication solution that can be accessed by Angular2 - for that, i found [an example repository on gitHub](https://github.com/RedFroggy/angular-spring-hmac). It implements HMAC-based authentication using JWT tokens with a custom service structure.

My issue now comes in understanding how the components of Spring Security work together in the background. As i understand the example, it implements a customised version of UserDetailsService and its environment using the UserDTO and LoginDTO. These access a MockUser-Service for example user data - which is what I want to avoid, instead accessing our Active Directory to authenticate users.

I am still digging through the repository trying to understand every customised class implementation and if I can customise the AuthenticationService to fit my needs, but I feel relatively lost.
What I am looking for are experiences in combining these three components, or with Spring Security and how exactly the default UserDetailsService and AuthenticationProviders interact, so I can try and fit the ActiveDirectory-logic into the token solution.

Alternatively, is there a way to combine the default-LDAP/AD-Configuration with a [default JWT-Solution such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42257585/spring-security-with-jwt)?

Comment: did u solve this?

Comment: I don't recall if or how I solved it. I am pretty sure I found a way to integrate with Active Directory, but I left that project quite a while ago. If I ever come across it, I will post it as the solution to the question